# How to delete a record in list using the Name in that record

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office365api

[image]

This is my list. How to Delete a record using Student Name not using ID.This is the code which I tried delete function using ID.

```
$("#btnDeleteStudent").click(function()
{
var IdNo = $("#txtDeleteStudent").val(); 

$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Student Details')/items("+IdNo+")", 
type: "DELETE",  
        headers: {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" ,
    "contentType": "application/json;odata=verbose" ,
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
             "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert("Item Deleted successfully");  
        },  
        eror: function(data) {  
            alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
        }  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I guess, you could click on "edit this list" and see, where that brings you.

Comment: sorry Forgot to mention. I need Rest API code to do this. I tried by using ID. But I want to delete a record using student name.

Comment: Does it work with ID?

Comment: Yes. It works with ID.

Comment: Then just take the ID corresponding to the student name and delete it.

Comment: Yes it works. But I want to try delete function using name, as I mentioned above.

Comment: So, what happens, when you type the user name in the input?

Comment: I used filter. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a CAML query to do the same.
Please refer these links for more details:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/467ca160-108d-4540-8dd7-4d5c8e3f6594/delete-list-items-through-caml-query?forum=sharepointdevelopment

[CAML Query - Delete 1 Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611352/caml-query-delete-1-item)

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43543-Delete-Lists-items-from-SharePoint-site-using.aspx

Thanks and regards,
Purushottam